# Problem updating an external jar in eclipse using gradle

Tags: java, gradle-eclipse

I am having trouble deleting an external dependency from my build path. I have searched this site and the web but have not found a good answer.

I use gradle 4.9 and eclipse 4.7.3a to manage my automated tests. I have placed external jars in a folder named artifact in a git project's root directory.

My `build.gradle` file contains this line in the dependencies section:

```
compile fileTree(dir: "./artifact", include: '*.jar')
```

Well and good, it all works.  However, when I try to delete a dependency using

Build Path > Configure Build Path... > Libraries > Project and External Dependencies
all the buttons, including Remove, are grayed out.

I can delete the file from the artifact directory and issue

```
gradle cleanEclipse
```

from the command line but when I open Eclipse and try to open the project (under Project Explorer) I get `'Open Project' has encountered a problem. The project description file (.project) for 'project name' is missing.`

After replacing the old jar with the new version (different file name of course), I tried running

```
gradle
```

which is supposed to recreate configuration files deleted by cleanEclipse.  No joy.  Next, I tried running

```
gradle build
```

But after restarting eclipse, still a failure.  The only thing that worked was to delete the project from eclipse and then to re-import it.

Is there an easier way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found an answer.

After deleting and copying in the new jar file into the artifact directory, in eclipse, I selected `Project > Clean ...`

Then I right-clicked on the project and selected `Gradle > Refresh Gradle project`

I guess writing the question got me thinking about how eclipse handles .project files.  Maybe this will help the next person.